# Is there a single word for "very likely"?

Tags: word-request

I want to say:

> They are **very likely to be** different.

But I find it a bit wordy, so I was wondering is there a single word that can be used like:

> They are _______ different.

I know maybe I can use **basically** here, but that seems to change the original meaning a bit to me, is that right?

Edit:
Is there a word that is stronger than "probably" in terms of probability?

Edit:
The context could be imagined as, I have asked some people from the streets to fill a questionnaire, but I can't be 100% sure if I have asked the same person twice, though it is very unlikely to happen.
So I want to say something like "These people are very likely to be different from each other."
Sorry for the terrible explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question seems to revolve around the **probability** that two things are different, not the **degree** to which they are different.  Using **basically** refers to the **degree** they are different.

A quick look at dictionary definitions shows that **probably** is synonymous with *most likely*, however from usage, why would the phrase **most probably** then exist?

> **likely to be** different

means a greater than a 50% chance

> **most likely to be** different

means something much greater than 50%, for example 90%

> **are** different
>   **definitely** different
>   **inherently** different
>   **completely** different
>   **totally** different

implies they are different with **certainty** (probability of 1.0)

To me, **most likely** has a greater chance of being different than just **probably**, whereas **likely** and **probably** are equivalent.  However, in your example, **most likely** still leaves the door open that they may be different, which makes phrasing difficult since the degree can always be modified by **more** or **very** which would make it **two** words, not **one** word.

Comment: "usually" or "normally" are two more possibilities.

Comment: I would also propose "almost certainly different" in place of "very likely to be different"

Answer (score 1):

For your edited-in example, *"I can't be 100% sure if I have asked the same person twice, though it is very unlikely to happen"* says it more clearly than the "They are ____ different" form would, but if determined you could consider using "**presumed**", "**presumably**", "**assumed**", "**typically**", or "**assumably**" (an ugly word IMHO).

If you want a separate statement, perhaps "It is unlikely that many people will be surveyed multiple times." or - stronger - "There's only a remote possibility of the same person being accidentally surveyed multiple times."

Answer (score 0):

You can say

They are **apt** to be different.